# mysql error keeps appearing - #1241- Operand should contain 1 column(s) - what does it mean?

Tags: mysql

When I run my query in mysql I keep getting the following error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How do I fix it?

```
SELECT( SELECT Tag, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM  (SELECT a.* 
FROM sport b 
join sport a 
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID > a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'Football') as ball
LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: Most likely, because you have an empty `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery has two columns: Tag and magnitude. This is not a scalar subquery.

The explanation of the error is that every subquery in the select-list must be a *scalar subquery*, which means it must return exactly one column and one row.

Example: Let's keep it simple and use queries of literal values, so we aren't even referencing tables. We assign a column alias for each item in the select-list.

```
SELECT 
  123 AS colum1,
  456 AS column2,
  (SELECT 789, 'abc') AS column3;
```

But wait! How can both 789 and 'abc' be assigned the column alias `column3`? That's ambiguous.

It turns out it's not allowed, and will generate an error message, *because* it's ambiguous. The subquery returned two columns, but this violates the rule that each item in the select-list of the outer query must be one column. We can fix it this way:

```
SELECT 
  123 AS colum1,
  456 AS column2,
  (SELECT 789) AS column3,
  (SELECT 'abc') AS column4;
```

Now each item in the select-list returns just one column.

A similar rule exists that requires a subquery in the select-list to return no more than one row, too:

```
SELECT 
  123 AS colum1,
  456 AS column2,
  (SELECT some_column FROM table_with_multiple_rows) AS column3;
```

This is wrong because the subquery returns multiple values, and there's no way to stuff all those values into one row of the result in the outer query.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. Make sure the subquery returns no more than one row. Either use a WHERE clause to specify one row (a condition on the primary or unique key of the table):

```
SELECT 
  123 AS colum1,
  456 AS column2,
  (SELECT some_column FROM table_with_multiple_rows
   WHERE unique_column = 789) AS column3;
```

Or else use LIMIT 1:

```
SELECT 
  123 AS colum1,
  456 AS column2,
  (SELECT some_column FROM table_with_multiple_rows
   LIMIT 1) AS column3;
```

Either way, your subquery will return at most one row (it could match zero rows, in which case the result of the subquery will be NULL).

Comment: I'm pretty confused now

Comment: @Beck: See my examples above.

Comment: now I'm being told that sport_ID is a Duplicate column name

Comment: Sounds like you have a derived table subquery where not all columns have distinct names. You'll have to alias one of them, which means you can't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: I have just checked and I don't

Comment: Well I'm not going to guess at what query you are running now. Good luck with that!

Comment: @BillKarwin OP seems to have reposted a new one http://stackoverflow.com/q/43373150/1415724

Answer (score 0):

The final select doesn't have any column specified. Try this:

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT Tag, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM  ( SELECT * 
FROM sport b 
join sport a 
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID > a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'Football') as ball
group by Tag
LIMIT 1 ) as ball2
```

Even b.sport_ID > b.sport_ID doesnt make sense.

Comment: Updated the Query. you have also missed group by clause when having a grouping function. Are you getting the same error or different?

Comment: I'm now getting this message #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Yes, it should have alias for every table. Have updated the query.